# Copy a file to multiple files with indices and preserve format

Tags: matlab, file

I have a `main.m` file. I want to copy this file into `main1.m`, `main2.m` and `main3.m`.

I do like this:

```
for k=1:3
   file=sprintf('main%d',k)
   copyfile('main.m',file);
end
```

This code only gives `main1`, `main2` and `main3`. I want append `.m` format to each of the file.

Many thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `.m` in `sprintf` like this:

```
for k=1:3
   file=sprintf('main%d.m',k)
   copyfile('main.m',file);
end
```

---

Here is an alternative to `sprintf` using `num2str`:

```
for k=1:3
    copyfile('main.m',['main',num2str(k),'.m']);
end
```